Smooth version of the splitting principle
Inspried by this MO question A manifold whose tangent space is a sum of line bundles and higher rank vector bundles  we  pose the  following question as a possible  smooth version of the  splitting  principle in k theory.
Recall that the  splitting  principle says the  following(Page  80 of  "Vector Bundles  and  K theory")
Splitting Principle: "Let  $E\to X$ be  a  vector  bundle on a  compact  Hausdorff space $X$, then there is  a  compact space $Y$ and  a  continuous function $f:Y\to X$  such that $f^*$ is injective in K theory and  $\mathbb{Z}/2$ cohomology. Moreover $f^*(E)$ is  a direct  sum of line  bundles.

Is this principle valid in the smooth context?  Can  $Y$  be choosen a  compact  manifold  of the same  dimension  as  $X$  and  $f$ a smooth map? What about the real  analytic  case?

Regardless of injectivity of $f^*$:

Is  there a  compact  manifold $X$, preferably orientable which does not admit any  smooth  surjection $f:Y\to X$ where $Y$ is  a  comact parralelizable  manifold?


The splitting principle constructs the space as a flag bundle. If $X$ is a compact smooth manifold, $Y$  will be as well, and $f$ will be a smooth map. I don't know anything about analyticity as I never thing of such things, but my gut says that it is also true in that context. The $Y$ will be of higher dimension.

@abx  Please read my  last  question again. The injectivity of  $f^*$ is no longer assumed. moreover do  you mean $T_X$ instead of  $T_Y$? Note that $Y$ is  parallelizable. So I  do not get your  comment.

@ThomasRot  Analytic  objects are discussed in Hirsch  Differential topology(For  upgrading  smooth  structures to  analytic  one)  and  also  Kobayashi and  Nomizu Differential geometry. Some times passing  from smooth to analytic  would creat interesting  advantures. I know splitting principal in the  CW  complex  setting  so please ellaborate  your  comment in smooth case. I  would  appreciate  if you provide  an answer.

Sorry, I exchanged $X$ and $Y$. I will delete my comment.

For the last question: The torus surjects to any connected compact manifold of the same (or lower) dimension

@ThomasRot  your  sentence in the  Holomorphic setting does not work unless the  base space would be Kahler. In the real case it is too degenerate. But what about the extra non degeneracy condition, say  submersion, what are some  examples that  base space is not  torus: $\mathbb{T}^n \to  M$ M  is not tori?

@ThomasRot Any way I  think that analytic objects are very interesting.As you know cartan solved the  local embedding theorem in case of  analytic case. So  they are worth of attention.  For example I  wonder the if  torus covering you mentioned  work in analytic case?

@AliTaghavi: If you want that the map is submersive, it will be a covering map (as you want the base and the manifold be of the same dimension. So $M$ non-tori are obtained by quotients of free actions of finite groups on tori.

@ThomasRot Yes I agree that dimX=dim Y implies that we have a  finite  covering space.But I meant arbitrary dimension. In this case we have a classificaton of  fibre bundle.

@ThomasRot  BTW you told  the torus  cover every manifold what is  your  argument for a least possible   degenerate  map? Because I remember a *** exercise  of  Hirsch book which says: Every manifold a  countable union of  homeomorphic copy of  open disk  is  R^n. So I guess that the mapping you would provide is very  degenerate

@AliTaghavi Sorry, I do not understand the exercise that you sited. I think that $S^1$ is a union of two copies of open intervals, but it is not even homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb R^1$.

@Z.M  sorry it was an increasing union in an open manifold. I bet that us a 3 star exercise in Hirsch diff topology

@Z.M namely if a manifold is a countable union of  open sets $U_n \subset U_{n+1}$ where $U_n$ is homeomorphic to $R^k$ then the manifold is homeomorphic to $R^k$

@Z.M I wonder if there is an analogue results (analogues to the above theirem in Hirsch book) in the context of algebraic geometry:?

Take an +n torus. Take a degree 1 map of the torus to the sphere. (Eg by collapsing the n-1 skeleton). Project the sphere to the first n coordinates in R^n. The composition of the map surjects the torus to the closed n disc. By modifying the maps a little, you can surject onto a wedge of k discs(attached to a common boundary point). You are essentialy free to map the k discs any way you like into any n manifold. As a compact manifold is covered by k open discs for some k, you can construct a surjective map from the n torus to an n manifold.

@ThomasRot what about the smoothneds of tge resulting surjective map. Approximation in $C^r$ topology $r>0$ is at hand but what about approximation of continuous object with smooth one?chapter 2 of Hirsch book

@ThomasRot in chapter 2 he frequently apply smooth approximation of $C^r$ maps for positive r but he apply to $C^0$ with caution and very rare

@Z.M  I was  talking  about exercise  15  page  21  Differential topology  Hirsch, 1976

You can make the map smooth

@ThomasRot  Ok Thanks

@ThomasRot  Your interesting MO  answer  below (My +1  for  that)  contains  materials about real  analytic  objects  the  paper  by  Michor and  Vizman  https://mathoverflow.net/a/466437/36688
So I think  you already familiar with analytic  structures
